# how to new WooCommerce my account custom tab with custom content

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint

How can i add new endpoints to WooCommerce my account menu and show my custom content with below array? endpoint=custom_endpoint, lable=endpoint lable, icon=any icon
just the below code return 404 eror

```html
// Enable endpoint
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars', 'myaccount_custom_endpoint_query_var' );
function myaccount_custom_endpoint_query_var( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars['custom-endpoint'] = 'custom-endpoint';

    return $query_vars;
}

// Endpoint displayed content
add_action('woocommerce_account_custom-endpoint_endpoint', 'display_custom_endpoint_content' ); 
function display_custom_endpoint_content(){
    echo '<p>' . __("hello") . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

May be following code will be helpful. Make Sure **Save Permalinks** after adding this code.

```
/**
 * Register New Endpoint.
 *
 * @return void.
 */
function register_new_item_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'new-item', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_new_item_endpoint');



/**
 * Add new query var.
 *
 * @param array $vars vars.
 *
 * @return array An array of items.
 */
function new_item_query_vars( $vars ) {

    $vars[] = 'new-item';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'new_item_query_vars' );


/**
 * Add New tab in my account page.
 *
 * @param array $items myaccount Items.
 *
 * @return array Items including New tab.
 */
function add_new_item_tab( $items ) {

    $items['new-item'] = 'New Menu';
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_new_item_tab' );


/**
 * Add content to the new tab.
 *
 * @return  string.
 */
function add_new_item_content() {
    echo 'New Contents here!';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_new-item_endpoint', 'add_new_item_content' );
```

Comment: dear @Sanket Thakkar its work well, thanks. could you please how to do it with array?
for ex. i need to add 3 custom tab:
for ex: tab1 :
the content of tab 1
tab2:
the content of tab 2
tab3:
the content of tab 3